# Is there a difference between typical a ZIP file and an APK file?

Tags: android, zip, apk

I know a typical APK file would have AndroidManifest.xml but that's not the aspect I ask for. I'm asking in terms of ZIP structure and headers, i.e. at a lower level perspective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any APK file is a valid ZIP file.  There's more to it than that - files that must be present, the fact that `zipalign` is normally used to align data structures within the file - but it's all valid ZIP.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, it is a completely standard ZIP file. I have had no problems working with an APK as a ZIP file using any tool I have tried.

Note that, as with regular ZIP files, not all entries will be compressed (varies by file type).

Comment: Thanks. I know not all ZIP files have to be compressed (also each file can be compressed using a different algorithm). Do you know which kind of files wouldn't be compressed for an APK and why?

Comment: It's not you can't compress all - it's rather for some types it makes no sense. Like for mp3's for example. Or anything that simply is already compressed and zip cannot make it more compressed.

Comment: @kolistivra: +1 to WebnetMobile's comment. The APK building tool `aapt` has a roster of standard file extensions for which it skips compression as adding build time with no significant value.