# Why jarsigner can sign Android apk?

Tags: java, android

From my experience in Java, `jarsigner` is used to generate signature for JAVA ARchive(JAR) files and verify the signatures for signed JAR files.

To my surprise, Android also use `jarsigner` to [sign the Android application package(APK)](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually) which is different from a JAR format.

Does the `jarsigner` not require the binary files to be packaged inside a JAR? How does it work under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APK files are just zip files with different contents.

[Is there a difference between typical a ZIP file and an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934674/is-there-a-difference-between-typical-a-zip-file-and-an-apk-file)

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html

```
The JAR feature enables the packaging of class files, images, sounds, and
other digital data in a single file for faster and easier distribution. A tool
named jar enables developers to produce JAR files. 

(Technically, any zip file can also be considered a JAR file, although when 
created by the jar command or processed by the jarsigner command, JAR files
also contain a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.)
```